# styling a <ui:spinner> in a lightning component

Tags: lightning, aura

Is there a way to style a  for example to place it within the page, i don't have control over it's style, is there a way to change the style of a ui spinner?

because i saw a class attribute, but i don't know what to put in it.

Comment: Have you already taken a look [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/spinners/)?

Answer (score 1):

So. This is the markup for the `ui:spinner`

```
<div class="spinner uiSpinner " role="alert" data-aura-rendered-by="23:2;a">
    <div class="loading" data-aura-rendered-by="24:2;a">
       <span data-aura-rendered-by="27:2;a" class="uiImage">
           <img data-aura-rendered-by="25:2;a" src="/auraFW/resources/aura/images/spinner.gif" class="spinner-img" alt="Loading">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since the spinner it's a message that's not much you can do with it. You could try tweak the css to style `.this div.loading` or maybe even the image `.this div.loading img` (maybe using `:before` and `:after` to add some content. But I'd suggest creating a custom loading spinner. And hiding/showing it with the loading event.

If you're only worried about placing it, since it's a div, you can always make a wrapper div and style that:

```
<div class="spinnerContainer">
    <ui:spinner/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to do it :

Component code :

```
   <aura:handler event="aura:waiting" action="{!c.showSpinner}" />
   <aura:handler event="aura:doneWaiting" action="{!c.hideSpinner}" />    


   <div class="{!v.showSpinner ? 'slds-spinner_container slds-show' : 'slds-spinner_container slds-hide'}" style="z-index:1">
    <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--large" role="alert">
        <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
        <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my client-side controller, i have this :

```
 showSpinner : function (component, event, helper) {       
    component.set("v.showSpinner",true);
},    
hideSpinner : function (component, event, helper) {       
    component.set("v.showSpinner",false);
},
```

And when i call my function where there is an $A.enqueueAction(...);
The spinner appear, and then disapear after the call.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, When i tired above code, loading icon loads on page load and unfortunately its not disappearing, not sure what I am missing there.
My use case is to load loading icon when user click on button and it needs to disappear after few second. Thanks in advance